# SAS- transform datetime format into another datetime

Tags: datetime, formatting, sas

How can I turn data like 01JAN14:00:03:05 into JAN14 in a data step?
I tried this but it's not working:

```
format ANOMES monyy7.;
```

but it returns 1.704E9...

Also I would need to know how to compare, for example:
in a proc sql:

```
sum(case when anomes='jan14' then 1 else 0 end)
```

is not working, I get: "Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types."

and also the > and <.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually DATETIME to DATE.

In SAS, DATETIME is number of seconds since 1/1/1960 00:00:00.  DATE is number of days since then.  As such they have very different numeric representations.

If you need it displayed as such, you can use the [DTMONYY format](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001585315.htm), like so.

```
format ANOMES dtmonyy7.;
```

Comment: thanks, but would you also tell me how to use comparisons with this format? (2nd part of the question).

Comment: That's really a different question. You need to use Datetime constants, so `'01JAN2014:00:00:00'dt`, or use input from your dtmonyy format.

Comment: but I want to use the field that I've just created (ANOMES) instead of the original... is that possible? How is the input syntax?

Comment: Ok I did this:´sum(case when live1 in (1,2) and anomes>='01FEB2014:00:00:00'dt
AND anomes<'01MAR2014:00:00:00'dt'